# ActiveMQ Classic Failover configuration

Tags: activemq-classic

Our API can send messages to our workerhost service using ActiveMQ.

```
activemq:failover:(tcp://brokera.domain.net:21249,tcp://brokerb.domain.net:21249)?maxReconnectAttempts=2&timeout=3000&initialReconnectDelay=2000
```

```
activemq:failover:(tcp://brokera.domain.net:21249,tcp://brokerb.domain.net:21249)?transport.maxReconnectAttempts=2&transport.timeout=3000&initialReconnectDelay=2000
```

We seem to be using the above URLs somewhat interchangeably. Note that the 2nd specifies the `transport` schema for two of the params. As far as we're able to tell, this has been working as expected in production, but admittedly, we hope that we've never really needed the failover!

I've done some testing (by manually stopping ActiveMq across the LB nodes) and the failover seems to work as expeced with both configs.

However, ActiveMQ don't say that the `maxReconnectAttempts` and `timeout` should be prefixed with `transport`, thus our initial concern was that they're not working as expected. See [here](https://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference)

Even more confusing, is that the ActiveMQ docs for TCP transport, say that client connections must ommit the `transport` schema. And even then, the two properties I mention above aren't in the list of supported params. See [here](https://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference)

We're looking to find out which is the correct connection string we should be using.
Optionally, a way to better test or ensure that those params are being used would be very useful.

Edit: We're using the .NET Core 6 client Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ version 1.8.0. Broker version 5.13.2

Comment: Which client are you using, what version of said client?  Java, .NET etc.  Provide some details please.

Comment: Good point. Edited original question. We're using the .NET Core 6 client Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ version 1.8.0. Broker version 5.13.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked documentation is for the Java JMS client which does not operate the same way when parsing the URI options as the NMS Openwire client so you need to reference the client documentation [here](https://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/providers/activemq/uri-configuration).

From what I see in the NMS client [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/providers/activemq/uri-configuration) the transport options must be prefixed with the 'transport.' tag in order for the client to parse them out of the URI.

Comment: Thanks Tim, you're correct. Answer accepted. Holy shi*. That must be one of the most confusing documentation setups I've ever seen in my life. Surely a company on the scale of apache could make it more clear which docs you're looking at.

Comment: Apache is not a company, but an open source software foundation and the work is done by volunteers.  If you want to improve the docs I'm sure the project will appreciate the help.

Comment: Apologies. My comment came across rather crass! In truth my frustrations are more with myself not having picked up what JMS and NMS actually stand for, and looking at the wrong stuff for a couple of days.